# Why wasn't Libby's spirit aware?

Tags: plot-explanation, dream-house

In the 2011 movie, *Dream House*, Will Atenton lives with his family in a house. Her wife calls him **Will**.

They find out about a crime that was committed 5 years earlier in the same house. Both get surprised by the news.

Later in the movie Will finds out his real name is **Peter Ward** and he seemingly murdered his family (which is revealed he was innocent near the end of the movie). He had changed his name to Will Atenton when he was in the asylum as the main suspect, but later discharged because of the lack of evidence against him. Now he realizes his family is just a mental projection and he had forgotton about the crime because he accidentally got shot in the head by his wife when the crime committed (she wanted to shoot the assaulter).

Peter tells his imaginary wife (Libby) that she and the children aren't alive and he is Peter Ward, not Will; which she refuses to believe. Libby also sees wounds on one of their childrens' body and wonders what those wounds are, which Peter tells her those are bullet wounds which Libby again refuses as bullshit. Peter still thinks he murdered his own family because of his record.

Near the end of the movie it's revealed that Jack, their neighbour's ex-husband, is the mastermind behind the crime. He tries to kill Peter, but Libby this time convinced of Peter's claims calls him by his real name **Peter**, then sounds the staff in the house to distract Jack and she succeeds (Showing she and the children aren't mental projections, but in fact spirits).

**My question**: Why isn't Libby's spirit aware of the situation in the start of the film? She and the children were murdered when her husband's name was Peter. He changed his name after the murders in the asylum. So why did her spirit call him Will from the start to near the end while she knew Peter? It made sense to call him Will if she was just a mental projection. Also, she didn't know they are spirits for most of the movie. Maybe these were intentional mistakes by the scriptwriter to seal the fact(s) from viewers? Or maybe they were aware from the start but pretend they don't know so that Peter can avenge and if they revealed everything from the start Peter wouldn't be able to avenge?

Comment: Because it's not Libby's spirit, she's in Peter/Will's delusions.  So, she calls him whatever he wants her to call him

Comment: @steelersquirrel If she is just in Peter/Will's delusions how was she able to distract Jack (the villain)? How could she move the hanging objects so that Jack shoot that point instead of Peter/Will in the room? Also, at the end Libby and children faded away like ghosts.

Comment: I read the question properly...I have seen this movie several times.  Peter/Will sees what he wants to see.  How do you know that Libby distracted Jack?  How do you know that it's not part of Peter/Will's delusion?  Same with the swaying of the hanging objects

Comment: Peter/Will had escaped to another location in the house. So he couldn't see Jack and the objects at that time to call it part of the delusion. Also, here the movie shows Jack's point of view: he doesn't see anybody. He just saw objects swayed out of nowhere. (The previous scene showed Libby for the viewer and later it became Jack's point of view)

Comment: Peter/Will doesn't have to be in the same room to see Libby in his delusions.  Sure, the filmmakers can put little things in the movie to make viewers question if the house was actually haunted or not and leave it up to the interpretation of the viewer.  But, you questioned why Libby called him Will.  The answer is because she was part of his delusion

Comment: But after Peter/Will realized his real name is Peter and his wife and children are delusions she still refused to call him Peter until the near end of the movie.

Comment: Because he was still struggling to fully accept that they were delusions

Comment: So were the Buick scene and the teenagers' scene also delusions?

Comment: No.  He was actually seeing the teenagers.  They didn't know that he was back.  Everyone in town actually thinks that Peter killed his family, so the teenagers used the house for a party spot while it was empty.  Peter was actually sleeping and living in the bad conditions of the house